# Expand $f(z)=\cos z$ about $z=\pi$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

I have a question regarding a complex Taylor expansion problem.

> Expand $f(z)=\cos z$ about $z=\pi$

Using the formula for the Taylor expansion, where $R_0$ is the radius

$$ f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n (z-z_0)^n \ (|z-z_0|<R_0) \ \ \text{for} \ \ a_n=\frac{f^{(n)}(z_0)}{n!} \ n=0,1,2,3,...$$

I get following answer:

$$ \cos z = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(2n)!}(z-\pi)^{2n} $$

But my professor gives the solution

$$ \cos z = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(2n)!}z^{2n} \ \ \text{for} \ \ (|z-\pi|<\infty) $$

Can someone please explain the logic in my professor's solution?

Thank you!

=========

In response to Lord Shark the Unknown's comment, here is my work.

$$ f(z)=\cos z, \ f'(z)=-\sin z, \ f''(z)=-\cos z, \ f'''(z)= \sin z, \ f^{(4)}(z) = \cos z \\ \therefore f(\pi) = -1, \ f'(\pi) = 0, \ f''(\pi)=1, \ f'''(\pi)=0, \ f^{(4)}(\pi)=-1$$

So, let $z_0=\pi$. Then

$$ a_0 = -1, \ a_1=0, \ a_2=\frac{1}{2!}, \ a_3=0, \ a_4=\frac{-1}{4!} \Rightarrow a_{2n}=\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(2n)!} \\ \therefore \cos z = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(2n)!} (z-\pi)^{2\pi} $$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to set $z-\pi=w$ and find the Taylor expansion about $0$ of $\cos w$:
$$
\cos z=\cos(w+\pi)=-\cos w=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{w^{2n}}{(2n)!}
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{(z-\pi)^{2n}}{(2n)!}
$$

Your professor’s series *is* convergent for every $z$, but the Taylor expansion about $\pi$ is usually assumed to be, as you say, of the form
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n(z-\pi)^n
$$
However, it’s a question of conventions: maybe the request was of a series for $\cos z$ that is convergent for $z$ in a neighborhood of $\pi$. In this case, the standard Taylor series at $0$ is as good as the Taylor series about any other point, because the cosine is an entire function.

Comment: Oh duh, that was a typo. The powers were supposed to be $n+1$, not $n$. That's my bad, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Kosta No problem. Typos are commonplace. `;-)`.

Comment: If you have a moment, could you answer my original question? Thank you!

Comment: @Kosta I did! See the last paragraph. It's the only interpretation which I can imagine.

Answer (score 2):

Alas I would say you are both wrong: $\cos z=\sum (-1)^n z^{2n}/(2n)!$
is not a Taylor expansion about $z=\pi$. And $\sum(-1)^n (z-\pi)^{2n}/(2n)!$
is not a Taylor series for $\cos z$. As $\cos(z-\pi)=-\cos z$, it is a Taylor series for $-\cos z$.

Comment: Please see my edit. I made a typo, it's fixed now.